# (python flask) [Solved] getting date form URL then add and subtract days, having error response function (ex ":sorry, wrong input dear customer~")

Tags: python, date, datetime, flask, url

I'm working on getting the date value from URL input, can add/subtract days, showing "This is wrong input of date,dear customer", such as   the input below

input:
*http://....   /data?date=2022-01-01&diff=5&op={add,del}

http://....   /data?date=2022-01-01&diff=13&op=add*

expect output:

The diff is: 5

The date is: 2022-01-01

The new_date is: 2022-01-14

```js
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from flask import Flask, request
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
# python testcodefmweb_clone.py
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/data')
def query_example():
   
    date = request.args['date']
    diff = request.args['diff']

    diff_int = int(diff)
    diff_date = int(date)

    date_in_system = datetime.strptime( date,  "%Y-%m-%d")
   
    new_date = date_in_system + datetime.timedelta(days = diff_int)

    return '''          
              <h1>The diff is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The date is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The new_date is: {}'''.format(diff, date_in_system , new_date)
             
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run app in debug mode on port 5000
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

[the website looks like for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMHSk.png) (new_date calculation not working)

[The python code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0mWi.png)

I search that the `[try] [except]` can help showing "This is wrong input of date, dear customer~"

**now I'm stocking on putting the operation add,del work to add/subtract days, and showing error for wrong input**

```js
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask import Flask, request
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/data')
def query_example():
   
    date = request.args['date']
    diff = request.args['diff']

    diff_int = int(diff)
    
    date_in_system = datetime.strptime( date,  "%Y-%m-%d")
   
    new_date_add = date_in_system + timedelta(days = diff_int )
    new_date_minus = date_in_system - timedelta(days = diff_int )

    return '''          
              <h1>The diff is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The date is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The new_date_minus is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The new_date_add is: {}'''.format(diff, date_in_system , new_date_minus ,new_date_add)
             
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run app in debug mode on port 5000
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

[(pic) the website looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULB2.png)

working on putting `[try] [except]` for showing user error "sorry, wrong input dear customer~" in code

the third one putting `[try] [except]`that the website is not working
[(pic) 3th code of website (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YouqQ.png)

```js
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask import Flask, request
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/data')
def query_example():
   
    
        date = request.args['date']
        diff = request.args['diff']

        diff_int = int(diff)
        
        date_in_system = datetime.strptime( date,  "%Y-%m-%d")
    
        new_date_add = date_in_system + timedelta(days = diff_int )
        new_date_minus = date_in_system - timedelta(days = diff_int )


        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            return '''          
                <h1>The diff is: {}</h1>
                <h1>The date is: {}</h1>
                <h1>The new_date_minus is: {}</h1>
                <h1>The new_date_add is: {}'''.format(diff, date_in_system , new_date_minus ,new_date_add)

        except ValueError:
            print("sorry, wrong input for date dear customer~")
          
             
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run app in debug mode on port 5000
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

**solved! see the code below**

```js
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask import Flask, request
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/data')

def query_example():
   
    try:
        date = request.args['date']
        diff = request.args['diff']
        op = request.args.get('op')
        
        
        diff_int = int(diff)
        
        date_in_system = datetime.strptime( date,  "%Y-%m-%d")
    
        new_date_add = date_in_system + timedelta(days = diff_int )
        new_date_minus = date_in_system - timedelta(days = diff_int )

        final_date = 0

        if op == "add":
            final_date = date_in_system + timedelta(days = diff_int )

        if op == "del":
            final_date = date_in_system - timedelta(days = diff_int )

   
    except Exception as e:
        return '''          
        
              <h1>捕捉錯誤資訊:  {}</h1>
              '''.format(diff+ str(e))

        

        
    
    return '''          
              <h1>The diff is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The date is: {}</h1>
              <h1>The op is: {}</h1>
              
              <h1>The final_date is: {}'''.format(diff, date_in_system , op, final_date)
             
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run app in debug mode on port 5000
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

[(pic)website showing to user the input is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsaeC.png)

[(pic)website for correct input result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vySPq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `new_date = date_in_system + datetime.timedelta(days = diff_int)` to `new_date = date_in_system +timedelta(days = diff_int)` since you import `timedelta`.

Is your expected output supposed to be:

```
The diff is: 5
The date is: 2022-01-01
The new_date is: 2022-01-06
```

This code snippet below should do what you want if the new date is `2022-01-06` and not `2022-01-14`:

```
from datetime import date,  datetime, timedelta

date = "2022-01-01"
diff_int = 5

date_in_system = datetime.strptime( date,  "%Y-%m-%d")
new_date = date_in_system + timedelta(days = diff_int)

print(new_date)
```